# "NoMethodError in Users#show" Hartl Chapter 7

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**NoMethodError in Users#show**

**Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

I've been following Hartl's rails tutorials for Rails 4.0 and I've been stuck on this for a couple of days now. The error highlights line 1 as the problem in the 'show.html.erb file'. Also, ruby's 'private' keyword doesn't work so i've hashed it out in 'users_controller.rb' which stops anymore errors. I'd be very, very grateful for any help. Thanks.

> 

**app/views/show.html.erb**

```
<% provide(:title, @user.name) %>
<div class="row">
  <aside class="span4">
    <section>
      <h1>
        <%= gravatar_for @user %>
        <%= @user.name %>
      </h1>
    </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new

        def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  #private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
end
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what the error was...

Comment: Updated above with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't set `@user` instance variable. You should have in your controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: It's there in 'users_controller.rb'above. Wait, no it isn't. Where about do i put it?

Comment: @Abraham wherever. It should just be public instance method of `UsersController` class.

Comment: @Abraham you should substitute your first `new` definition with `show`.

Comment: I've add "def show" etc to the top and now the page loads. I'm surprised i missed that one. Code blindness must have set in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you have two problems in your code:

**first** : you have two functions named `new`, the first one should be `show`.

**second** : you missed `end` in the end of the second function (move it from the controller's ending)

Comment: Oh yeah. I've moved end from the controller's ending. I assume that will enable 'private' to work now?